# pyplot plot freezes (not responding)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, freeze

I am struggling with pyplot from the matlpotlib library. The figure freezes already when I try to create the plot:

```
plt.figure()
plt.ion()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211) #Here it freezes
plt.title('test', fontsize=8)
plt.xlim(-1700, 1700)
plt.ylabel('x-axis')
plt.xlabel('y-axis')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
...do something else
```

I have only worked with Pyqt plots, but this time I would like to solve my Problem without multithreading since I do not care if the plot stops my code for a short moment. The problem is, the script does not stop but continues to run and does not wait until the figure is completely created. (time.sleep() does not help). Is there a solution without threads?

Cheers,
James

Ps.: If I add a breakpoint after the code and run in debug mode, there is no Problem (obviously).

Comment: How (where) do you run this? It's obviously hard to reproduce as running this as a script works just fine (in the sense that a plot is created, immediately closed and `...do something else` is executed). Adding more details like versions, backend, exact running procedure (or IDE from which it is run) is needed.

Comment: So I am using Pycharm 2016.2.3 with Python 2.7 and I honestly do not know what is meant with backend. To emphasize my problem: Îf I change "do sth else" to time.sleep(5) the plot shows up after 5 seconds. The same thing happens with my code: The following measurement loop blocks the main (single) thread and therefore pyplot cannot coomplete the plot. I am looking to some kind of feedback of the plot, so that the script only continues when the plot has been built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this one working as you want it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.ion()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211) #Here it freezes
plt.title('test', fontsize=8)
plt.xlim(-1700, 1700)
plt.ylabel('x-axis')
plt.xlabel('y-axis')
plt.grid()
plt.draw() # draw the plot
plt.pause(5) # show it for 5 seconds
print("Hallo") # continue doing other stuff
```

Comment: Yes it does; If I add time.sleep(5) after it, the plot completes bevore the timeout. But I guess if I want to keep the plot through my whole code, I should change to multithreading... Otherwise it always crashes when I accidentally click on it.

Answer (score 6):

For me, it worked using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Comment: Thanks! This also worked for me, but to give a bit more context, this is changing the backend renderer of matplotlib. For whatever reason, presumably after an ubuntu upgrade, the default 'GTK3Agg' renderer stopped working for me.

Answer (score 1):

add `plt.show(block=True)` is also worked

Answer (score 0):

Using plt.clf is a simple addon to close figure after the plot is completed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.ion()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211) 
plt.title('test', fontsize=8)
plt.xlim(-1700, 1700)
plt.ylabel('x-axis')
plt.xlabel('y-axis')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
plt.clf() # Here is another path
```

Answer (score 0):

`fig = plt.figure()` will cause the freeze for my PyQt5 as well.

I don't the exactly reasons but find nice workaround and works for me.

Workaround:

```py
from matplotlib.Figure import Figure
fig1 = Figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot()
```

You can find more examples from
https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-matplotlib/

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue: My figure window was a blank white window. It used to freeze if a figure was generated.

The reason being an incompatible matplotlib backend.

The backend of the current environment can be found using

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

The default backend in Windows systems is `QtAgg`, which means **Agg** rendering in a **Qt** canvas.
This backend can be activated in IPython with `%matplotlib qt`.

Adding the following codeblock for changing my backend to `Qt5Agg` resolved my issue.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

The permissible backends are `['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'GTK4Agg', 'GTK4Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'QtAgg', 'QtCairo', 'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']`. Additional frameworks/packages may be required to make the chosen backend work. E.g., `TkAgg` requires the `tk` interactive framework.

See https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/backends.html for details.